I want to control 4 servo motors, with pwm signal through a c program running on an Atmega32a
so i have an atmega32a, and i want to configure PORTD pin3, pin4, pin5 and pin7 to send a PWM signal to a specific servomotor to rotate it 90 degrees, im gonna have 4 servos that when called upon, rotates 90 degrees. This currently doesnt work and im not sure why i have set up a timer and the pwm signal. I also have UART set up to eventually send data from a c++ program to the c program with to control what servo is rotating. (im hoping that i have explained enough, im can try to answer any questions about the code)
this is my code:
/*
 * send my name.c
 *
 * Created: 04/04/2024 10.32.40
 * Author : chris
 */ 
#define F_CPU 8000000UL             //Defining the frequency of the CPU. 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setup_uart() {
    // Set baud rate
    UBRRH =  0;                             //Used for calculating F_CPU/16(baud rate)-1 = 51
    UBRRL =  51;                            //Therefor its under 255 and we only have to use the low part not the high part.
    UCSRB = (1 << TXEN)|(1 << RXEN);
}

void uart_transmit(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)));

    // Put data into buffer, sends the data
    UDR = data;
}

uint8_t uart_receive() {
    // Wait for data to be received
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC)));

    // Get and return received data from buffer
    return UDR;
}

/////////////////////SETTING UP THE SERVOS AND PWM SIGNAL 



void PWM_gen(){
    DDRD = 0xFF; //Port D som output
    
    TCCR1A |= 1<<WGM11 | 1<<COM1A1 | 1<<COM1B1; //configuration af TC1 "Fast PWM mode, non-inverted output on OC1A.;  
    TCCR1B |= 1<<WGM12 | 1<<WGM13  | 1<<CS10; //Sets TC1 for a prescaler of 1 (no prescaling) and Fast PWM mode.
    TIMSK  |= 1<<OCIE1A; //Enables the output compare interrupt for OC1A.
    
    ICR1 = 19999; // maksimale værdi for counter fra databladet beregnes duty cycle.

    sei(); // Enables global interrupts. som gør at kalde interrupt service routine (ISR), som sætter PORTD to 0xFF (all pins high).
    
    DDRD |= (1 << PORTD3) | (1 << PORTD4) | (1 << PORTD5) | (1 << PORTD7); // PD5,4,3,7 som output-pins.
}


void servo_rotate(uint8_t servo_number){
    

     
    switch(servo_number) {
        case 1:
        
            if (TCNT1 >= 800 && TCNT1 <= 2300)
            {
                
                if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND3)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
                {
                    PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND3);
                }
            }
        
        break;
        
        
        case 2:
        
            if (TCNT1 >= 800 && TCNT1 <= 2300)
            {
            
                if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND4)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
                {
                    PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND4);
                }
            }
        
        break;
        
        
        case 3:
            if (TCNT1 >= 800 && TCNT1 <= 2300)
            {
                
                if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND5)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
                {
                    PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND5);
                }
            }
        
        break;
        
        
        case 4:
            if (TCNT1 >= 800 && TCNT1 <= 2300)
            {
                
                if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND7)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
                {
                    PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND7);
                }
            }
        
        break;
        
        default:
        break;
    }
    
}


ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    
    PORTD = 0xFF;
}




int main(void) {
    PWM_gen();
    setup_uart();

    while (1) {
        servo_rotate(1);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        servo_rotate(2);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        servo_rotate(3);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        servo_rotate(4);

        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}


A little update, i made it work so that i can control the servo, but when i have made them rotate to a position and then want to send a new PWM signal to that pin i wont allow me to do so? this is my new and improved code (also i cant make the uart protocal run side by side with the code in my main)
NEW CODE:

    // CODE DER VIRKER (Bestemt, konstant bevægelse for hver pins)

#define F_CPU 1000000UL             //Defining the frequency of the CPU.

// CODE DER VIRKER (Bestemt, konstant bevægelse for hver pins)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>

//SETUP UART

void setup_uart() {
    // Set baud rate
    UBRRH =  0;                             //Used for calculating F_CPU/16(baud rate)-1 = 51
    UBRRL =  12;                            //Therefor its under 255 and we only have to use the low part not the high part.
    UCSRB = (1 << TXEN)|(1 << RXEN);
}

void uart_transmit(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)));

    // Put data into buffer, sends the data
    UDR = data;
}

uint8_t uart_receive() {
    // Wait for data to be received
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC)));

    // Get and return received data from buffer
    return UDR;
}


//SETUP PWM AND SERVO MOVE

void set_timer_pwm(){
    DDRD = 0xFF; //Port D som output
    
    TCCR1A |= 1<<WGM11;   // | 1<<COM1A1 | 1<<COM1A0 | 1<<COM1B1 | 1<<COM1B0 | 1<<FOC1A | 1<<FOC1B; //configuration af TC1 "Fast PWM mode, non-inverted output on OC1A.
    TCCR1B |= 1<<WGM12 | 1<<WGM13  | 1<<CS10; //Sets TC1 for a prescaler of 1 (no prescaling) and Fast PWM mode.
    TIMSK  |= 1<<OCIE1A; //Enables the output compare interrupt for OC1A.
    
    ICR1 = 19999; // maksimale værdi for counter fra databladet beregnes duty cycle.

    sei(); // Enables global interrupts. som gør at kalde interrupt service routine (ISR), som sætter PORTD to 0xFF (all pins high).
    
    DDRD |= (1 << PORTD5) | (1 << PORTD4) | (1 << PORTD3) | (1 << PORTD7); // PD5,4,3,7 som output-pins.
}

void rot_servo(uint8_t servo_nummer){
    switch (servo_nummer){
        case 1: 
            if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND3)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
            {
                PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND3);
            }
        break; 
        
        case 2:
            if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND4))
            {
                PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND4);
            }
        break;
        
        case 3:
            if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND5))
            {
                PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND5);
            }
        break;
        
        case 4:
        if (TCNT1 >= 1000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND7))
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND7);
        }
        break;
        
    }
}

void rot_servo_back(uint8_t servo_nummer){
    switch (servo_nummer){
        case 1:
        if (TCNT1 >= 2000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND3)) // hvis TCNT1 er over eller lig med 2000, så clear PD3
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND3);
        }
        break;
        
        case 2:
        if (TCNT1 >= 2000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND4))
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND4);
        }
        break;
        
        case 3:
        if (TCNT1 >= 2000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND5))
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND5);
        }
        break;
        
        case 4:
        if (TCNT1 >= 2000 && bit_is_set(PORTD , PIND7))
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PIND7);
        }
        break;
        
    }
}


int main(void) {
    
    set_timer_pwm(); 
    setup_uart(); 
    
    

    while(1){
        
            
        
        if (TCNT1 >= 800 && TCNT1 <= 2300)
        {
                
            rot_servo(1);
            rot_servo_back(2); 
            rot_servo(3);
            rot_servo_back(4); 
            //this under here doesnt work 
            rot_servo(1);
            rot_servo_back(1);
    
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    
    PORTD = 0xFF;
}



If i write in my main rot_servo(1) and then a little delay and then rot_servo_back(1) it wont actually rotate the servo to another position.

So can you focus your [mre] and the title to the problem you already get with a single servo? Did you ever successfully control one servo similar to what you try here? Also, the servos which your question makes me think of are unsuitable to be controlled by means of incremental rotation, especially not by 90 degrees (which I read as your goal from "rotate it 90 degrees". Please describe the kind of servos which are PWM controlled and able to meaningfully rotate by 90 degrees, in contrast to the PWM servos I know, which meaningfully only can rotate to. They have a position range.

Concerning your edits to the question. Please, as long as you do not have any answers which you would invalidate, do strive for a good question according to [ask]. The history of your insights is irrelevant (apart from maybe "failed things I tried"). Try to keep your post up to date and free of outdated clutter.

I recommend to also edit for: a) less empty lines b) no horizontal scrolling needed c) cleaner indentation d) consistent commenting style (I think some tabulators messed up your new lines...) e) no dead code, i.e. do not add "new and improved", replace the old code f) remove the added questions on parallel execution, UART protocol, non-shown C++ code g) any funcitonality not directly involved
